# Google Vision API similar files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I prepare some solution for grouping documents using Google Vision API. I would like grouping documents by something like template of document.

If i firsty scan invoice from one company and a few days after a scan additional other invoice from the same company, can I check they are simlar?

Comment: You may try a thing called a "dhash" or https://github.com/Nakilon/dhash-vips

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be done by default with the Vision API.
You could use the visionapi to detect text using OCR and see if this gives enough information to do the clustering.

Otherwise you'd have to make a custom implementation. You could train a neural network to do classification, or maybe an easier "dumber" solution depending on how your input is structured.